# ac only works on high

Tags: electrical, ac, dodge, ram

[image]Last year I changed out my father's 2003 Dodge Ram van's blower motor resistor after hearing complaints about his AC only working on high.

I did some googling and found that many people pointed their fingers at the blower motor resistor being the problem so I swapped it for a new one and it worked...for about a month and a half.

Could there be another problem causing the AC to work only on high, or is it the resistor again?

Comment: Sounds like you just got a bad resistor pack. I've had one die on me in a short time. In my truck, it goes strait to high fan speed and stays there with the truck shut off. You have to pull the fuse until you get a new resistor for it.

Comment: thanks for passing on the knowledge! What does lulling the fuse do/prevent?

Comment: If not the resister i would replace the control switch for the blower.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 probably has to pull the fuse because it's likely a pwm system with a control module and not really a resister. in your case it wouldn't help. you see this in newer hyundais and kias as well.

Comment: @Ben - Yah, it's because of how GM does their thing. I don't know why they provide power all the time to the blower resistor, but that's the way they designed it. Especially when the blown resistor provides a means to give full power to the fan. I guess my comments have confused things for the OP.

Comment: changed out the resistor today and it works again. Thank you all.